# PHP foreach loop warning illegal string offset

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a little problem with a simple loop. 
I have a data like this :

```
$PRODUCT = [

'title' => 'Blouse',
'lines' => [

    'variants' => [
        [
            'price' => 112.34,
            'options' => [
                'size' => 'small',
                'color' => 'yellow',

            ]
        ],
        [
            'price' => 156.33,
            'options' => [
                'size' => 'small',
                'color' => 'blue',

            ]
        ],
    ],
  ]
```

I need to create a new table like this:

```
$options => [
        'size',
        'color'
    ]
```

I'm trying to get only to array with key `'options'` in my loop, and I even have data which I need, but I have warning:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'options'
```

My loop looks like this:

```
$options = [];

foreach ($PRODUCT['lines'] as $variant){
    foreach ($variant as $item) {
      $options[] = $item['options'];
    }
 }
```

Where is my mistake? I know that `'price'` is not an array, but what does to have no warnings in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You miss a level in your array. Try this :

```
$options = [];

foreach ($PRODUCT['lines']['variants'] as $variant){
    foreach ($variant as $item) {
      $options[] = $item['options'];
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use array_column.

```
$options = array_column($PRODUCT['lines']['variants'], 'options');
var_dump($options);
```

Array_column will get all array items called 'options' and save them to the $options variable.

https://3v4l.org/bJKX4